# laravel: mailgun sending double emails

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, mailgun

I try mailgun and it works to send an email, but the problem is when I run the function, it sent double email.

the function is like this:

```
public function sendEmail($id){
    try{
        $user= Users::find($id);
        $data = array('username'=>$user->name, 'email'=>$user->email);
        Mail::send('emails.hapstics', $data, function ($message) use($data){
            $message->to($data['email'], $data['username'])->subject('Test Subject');
        });

        return redirect('leads');
    }
    catch(Exception $e){}
}
```

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=*hidden
MAIL_PASSWORD=*hidden
MAIL_FROM_NAME=*hidden
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=*hidden
MAILGUN_SECRET=*hidden
```

Comment: maybe this is due to `$mail->to()` because you might defined it mail.php too and it is fetching from config file too.

Comment: just remove the `to` entry from your mail.php and hardcode the email address in `mail->to()`

Comment: What version of laravel are you on?

Comment: Are you clicking the button twice by accident? Could this be an ajax request? The code you posted doesn't look like it has any issues. Can you give some more context? What does your view look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern for sending email.

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
Mail::send('emails.reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
                $m->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');

                $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send mail using Mailable as laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#generating-mailables

tutorial https://appdividend.com/2018/03/05/send-email-in-laravel-tutorial/